# Hibernate criteria.list() returns duplicates

Tags: java, hibernate

I know this kind of question has been asked thousands of times already, but I think I have a different problem. So, I have a class A, which has a collection of objects of class B and a getter for this collection:

```
public class A {
     private String Id;
     private ArrayList<B> bees;
     public ArrayList<B> getBees(){
        ArrayList<Criterion> criterions = new ArrayList<>();
        criterions.add(Restrictions.eq("classAId", this.Id));        
        return (ArrayList<B>)DatabaseHelper.getObjectByCriteria(criterions, B.class);
     }
}
```

And DatabaseHelper.getObjectByCriteria code:

```
public static List getObjectByCriteria(ArrayList<Criterion> cr, Class classType){        
        List result = new ArrayList();        
        Session session = MyHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(classType);        
        if (cr != null){
            for (Criterion criterion : cr){
            criteria.add(criterion);
            }        
        }
        result = criteria.list();
        if (session.isOpen()){
            session.close();
        }         
        return result;

    }
```

When I run this query (select * from table_b where id = 123) in MySQLWorkbench I get two different rows with different values.
However, the "result" list returned by DatabaseHelper.getObjectByCriteria contains two indentical objects with identical ids and values.

I don't use any kind of hibernate annotations

I have show_sql property set to "true", and I checked the real query being run by hibernate and its ok

Comment: Looking at the query `select * from table_b where id = 123` it seems `id` is the primary key in `table_b`. Is it so?. By the way `criterions.add(Restrictions.eq("Id", this.Id));` you are using `this.Id`, I doubt it you are using Id of `ClassA` and not `ClassB`. Not sure if that is what you wanted? And what is the value of `this.Id` you are using in the code?

Comment: exactly as you said, id is the primary key in the table B. And yes, I'm using the Id of class A because I have a field "classAId" in class B. Eddited according to your remark

Comment: So shouldn't it be `criterions.add(Restrictions.eq("classAId", this.Id));`. Also if id is primary key in table B, how come you have records in table_B with same primary key? So did changing it to `classAId` in criterions help? And I am assuming `classAId` is mapped to `id` column of table_B?

Comment: I eddited my question. I have to entries with the same PK because it's not the only PK in that table

Comment: And I am assuming `classAId` in `B.class` is mapped to `id` column of `table_B`?

Comment: its a bit different. Class A has a field "ID". Class B has a field "ClassAId" a that's it. So when I want to fetch class A related Bees I just pass class A's ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108090/discussion-between-madhusudana-reddy-sunnapu-and-sergey-maslov).